# FactoryGirl: RecordInvalid with association length minimum validation on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I have model `Question` that is `has_many` `Answer`. I require a question to have at least one answer and I'm testing with `rspec`

```
validates :answers, length: { minimum: 1 }
```

My factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :question do
    text "Enunciado de la pregunta"
    transient do
      answers_count 2
    end

    after(:create) do |q, ev|
      create_list(:answer, ev.answers_count, question: q)
    end
  end

  factory :answer do
    text "Enunciado de la respuesta"
  end
end
```

But when I do `create(:question)` in the spec file it throws a `RecordInvalid` exception (create tries to save model, but associated answers are created after create).

Tried changing to `after(:build)` but it doesn't work as well.

How can I build the needed answers preserving the transient `answers_count` parameter without callbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of tries, it went working with this:

```
after(:build) do |q, ev|
  q.answers = build_list(:answer, ev.answers_count, question: q)
end
```

Why? If someone know it, it would be great to have it explained.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, you'll need to create the assocations before saving the Question.

I think that you might want to do something like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :question do
    ...
    answers { [association(:answer, answers_count: 2 )] }
  end
end
```

or perhaps the `build_list` method could help:

```
after(:build) do |q, ev|
  build_list(:answer, ev.answers_count, question: q)
end
```

I was able to get it working with `after(:build)`. See [docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations) for `after(:build)` and its order of callbacks.

I got it to work in mongo with this setup:

```
#spec/models/question_spec.rb
describe Question do
  let!( :question ){create :question}

  it 'should work', :focus do
    expect( question ).to be_valid
    puts question.inspect
    puts question.answers.inspect
  end
end

#spec/factories/questions.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :question do
    text "Enunciado de la pregunta"
    transient do
      answers_count 2
    end

    after(:build) do |q, ev|
      create_list(:answer, ev.answers_count, question: q)
    end
  end

  factory :answer do
    text "Enunciado de la respuesta"
  end
end

#models/question.rb
class Question
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic

  field :text,      type:String

  has_many :answers
  validates_presence_of :answers
end

#models/answer.rb
class Answer
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic

  field :text,      type:String

  belongs_to :question
end
```

My test out put was this:

```
Run options: include {:focus=>true}
#<Question _id: 590a20ef8a681843088580bb, text: "Enunciado de la pregunta">
[#<Answer _id: 590a20ef8a681843088580ba, text: "Enunciado de la respuesta", question_id: BSON::ObjectId('590a20ef8a681843088580bb')>, #<Answer _id: 590a20ef8a681843088580bc, text: "Enunciado de la respuesta", question_id: BSON::ObjectId('590a20ef8a681843088580bb')>]
.

Finished in 0.16217 seconds (files took 2.87 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

Comment: Could yo explain why this works with `validates_presence_of`? And more important, why that validator is better than `length: { minimum: 1 }`?

Comment: UPDATE: Anyway, tried your example and it keeps crashing at `create :question` with `Answers can't be blank`. I don't use mongo if it makes sense.

Comment: Okay, `length: { minimum: 1 }` should work, I verified that, but it didn't work for me earlier in my testing, so I thought that was the problem. Oops. So, do you have a `answer` factory? Can you post that code?

Comment: Look at my code, it was already there. Just after `factory :question` definition.

Comment: I didn't work. However, got it working changing the `after(:build)` block to `q.answers = build_list(:answer, ev.answers_count, question: q)`. But I don't know why it doesn't work unless I put it as said.